# Chart JS, y line border appears wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I've been trying out this Chart JS, newest version.
I tried to create dotted lines, and it works, but my chart renders a solid line from 0 to the top on the first X child.

Is there anyway to hide all lines from the x axis to appear?

On the X, i use

```
grid: { display:false }
```

```
y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        ticks: {
          color: "#000,
          font: {
            size: 12,
            weight: "bold",
          },
        },
        border: {
          dash: [2, 2],
        },
        grid: {
          color: "fff",
        },
```

Comment: maybe you can try adding "display: false," to the border node.